# Sending first email to admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, publify

I'm trying to make `Publify` works. There is no email sent even if I told the contrary by the interface. What could be the reason? Why my local server cannot send any email?

This happens at the first running of the local server. I am told by the Publify back-office interface to enter my email so I can later connect to the b-o. Entering it results in the publication of a message ("we have sent you an email"), but I've received nothing.

Comment: You should better describe your problem.

Comment: This happens at the first running of the local server. I am told by the Publify back-office interface to enter my email so I can later connect to the b-o. Entering it results in the publication of a message ("we have sent you an email"), but I've received nothing and don't understand why not.

Comment: You should include this in your question, using [edit]. I believe you still should include more. There is a lack of information to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you. When I understand more about my problem, I modify my initial message further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this is how I solved it (using rails `4.2.0` and ruby `2.1.5` on `Ubuntu 14.10`):

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost:3000" }
                                         # change host and port if needed 

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:         'smtp.gmail.com',  # don't change
  domain:          'mail.google.com', # don't change
  port:            587,               # don't change
  user_name:       'user@gmail.com',  # change to your gmail 
  password:        'password',        # change to your pass on gmail
  authentication:  :plain,            # don't change
  enable_starttls_auto:  true         # don't change
}
```

**Edit**:

You have to reinstall Publify or somehow make it send admin mail once more, that is if you failed to send it at the first place.

And one more thing: Publify didn't work as expected with my setup. There was an issue with building other pages and with bootstrap javascripts. I did manage to solve bootstrap problem with bootstrap sprockets gem but the first one persisted and got me leaving Publify for LocomotiveCMS (which btw works like a charm, but doesn't support Rails 4 yet).

When I have time I will probably try it again but this time with Rails < 4.2.